# MySQL and C Programming

Tags: c++, mysql, c, odbc

I just have a little question with regards to connecting C to MySQL.
Well, I already have an existing MySQL server installed on my system but when I tried to run my code with the `#include <mysql.h>` in the header, it says that the path does not exist. So, I placed the *include* folder of my MySQL to the "includes" folder of my compiler making this code: `#include <include/mysql.h>`. At this far, the compiler recognized it but gives me a bunch of errors that I don't know what.

Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: I think the formatting swallowed a piece of your question (the name of your include file) and what errors do you get? and for what exactly do you need alternatives?

Comment: We could help you better if you add what errors you are getting to your question.

Comment: Can you explain more ? it seems a Makefile error. Check your Makefile and simplify your question, we cannot see your mind..

Regards..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `$(mysql_config --libs)` and `$(mysql_config --cflags)` in your `gcc` command.

You need to include the header files and link the libraries. For mysql you can find them using `mysql_config` command. This command is available if you have installed the library and development header file properly. `mysql_config --cflags` and `mysql_config --libs` will show which include paths and libraries are needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `syntax error before "SOCKET"` error is explained [in this blog post](http://www.technowise.in/2009/08/fixing-socket-does-not-name-type-error.html).  In short, you need to include <winsock.h> before mysql.h.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that when you say you are running your code, you are actually trying to compile and build.

If this is the case, the most likely problem is that you haven't defined the location of the MySQL head file location for you compiler.  For gcc, for example, header file locations are defined on the command line when you run the compiler.

Comment: I can't give all 140 errors and 19 warnings but this is the first one that appears: [Error] C:\PROGRA~1\C-FREE~1\mingw\include\mysql\mysql_com.h:291: error: syntax error before "SOCKET"

Comment: Yes, if you look at the link that johntotetwoo posted you will notice in the output section, "-I/usr/include/mysql".  This defines the location of the MySQL headers for the compiler.  From your error message, it looks like mingw can't find the location of mysql.h.  Your are running on Windows, so you can't use that example entirely, but you can look at mingw's documentation to figure out how to include the correct paths.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple C program that connects to MySQL Database server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html)